# Traffic Source Attribution Shift during User Sign-Up Process on a Single Domain Website

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

**The Issue:**
Our events are firing correctly, but the traffic source attribution changes unexpectedly.

Initially, the source shows as 'paid social,' but after the user creates an account and logs in via an email link, the source shifts to 'direct/unassigned'. This happens despite our website, checkout pages, and emails all being on the same domain.

**User Journey & Events:**

- Stage 1: User lands on OurWebsite.com (Traffic Source: Paid Social)
- Stage 2: User navigates to /login and 'generate_lead' event fires (Source still correct)
- Stage 3: User clicks a magic link in their email to log in
- Stage 4: User lands on /your-details, triggering 'sign_up' event (it's here the source changes to Direct/Unassigned)
- Stages 5 & 6: User navigates through /plan-details and /complete-setup with 'begin_checkout' and 'purchase' events firing (Source remains Direct/Unassigned)

**What we want to solve**
How can we maintain the original traffic source (e.g., paid social) throughout the session?

**Already checked:**
GA4 Referral Exclusion list
Session timeout
Cross-domain tracking